# Repeat message with for-loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, repeat

I have an assignment in school where we should grab a text string taken from a promt and then let an alert print the text string 10 times. But we have to use a for-loop. But I can't seem to get it to work even though I read all the pages covering this.

```
function buttonAction7() {
    var someMsg = prompt("Write something");    
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        someMsg+someMsg; 
    }   
    alert(someMsg);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The statement:

```
someMsg+someMsg;
```

Doesn't actually *do* anything, it just returns a logical value.  You'll probably want to assign this value to something, such as:

```
someMsg = someMsg + someMsg; // Notice assignment operator, we're now actually modifying the value of someMsg
```

If you wanted to build a string with the message 10 times, you'd probably want something more like:

```
var someMsg = prompt("Write something");
var msg = '';

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    msg += someMsg + '\n'; // Add a line break after each iteration
}

window.alert(msg);
```

Comment: Don't teach the new programmer to omit curley braces please :(

Comment: You don't need curly braces after a for-loop @jbabey ?

Comment: @user1394799 - You don't *need* curly braces if there's just a single line of code in your loop.  However, some consider omitting them bad practice because if you add more code in your loop, you might not notice and break things.  The curly braces in `if` blocks and `for` blocks clarify *exactly* what's being executed.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand what you're asking, you want the alert to display the string 10 times back to back in the same alert window? (like "Write somethingWrite somethingWrite something..."):

If that is correct then your issue is your computation inside your for loop.  You are simply add the two strings together, but doing nothing with the result.  You need to save the result back to the someMsg variable on each loop iteration, like this:

```
var someMsg = promt("Write something");
var output = "";

for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
   output = output + someMsg;
}

alert(output);
```

You see how the result of output+someMsg is being saved back to the variable output with each iteration.  You can also write that short hand like this:

```
output += someMsg;
```

Comment: Note that this way you'll end up with 1024 copies of the original string, not 10 copies. Fix hint: use a separate output buffer

Comment: That is definitely correct. I edited my answer to show that.  Mike's first answer is accurate because he was already using the separate output buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var someMsg=prompt("Write Something");


var i;

for(i=0;i<10;i++){
   alert(someMsg);
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question + your are complicating thing by doing an inverted loop

Comment: how's this @Weedoze ?

Comment: You were using `prompt` inside the loop + as I said *why the inverted loop starting at 9 and going to 0* ?

Comment: because I just want it to print 10 times when he enters the text in the prompt, I change it does this make sense to you now?. @Weedoze

Comment: I know how the for loop works.. It is just that for a beginner it will be easier for him to understand a loop from 0 to 10 than from 9 to 0

Comment: are you satisfy with the now @Weedoze?, I think its more simple now to understand.